# Categories for employers

Tags: feature-request, jobs

I've worked for enough people to know there are certain areas I don't want to work in.

For example, I do not want a job in finance, and I don't want to work for a contracting company (even as a permanent employee) because they can make me work for a finance company.

I would love if there was some way to indicate this preference so employers aren't wasting their time when contacting me.

Also, I am specifically looking to work at startups, and would like some way to indicate this as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just write it into your personal statement? Is that not the perfect place for this kind of information.

Otherwise, you would have to force every employer to select a category... And rejecting an offer by clicking "not interested" is trivial to do.

Comment: This is not a bad idea, but my experience is that they are not actually reading my personal statement before contacting me.  I was hoping to give them an automated way (tag filtering?) to not waste their own time.  But I guess if they're not going to read my personal statement, I'm not wasting their time by rejecting their offer.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I am skeptical of categories. They sound logical but one inevitably ends up trying to force a taxonomy on things.